# How to optimize a delete on table which doesn't have any primary key but has a column which has TimeStamp?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

My process is doing a *insert into* to a backup table 'B from a table 'A' which gets updated daily[truncate and load] in the azure sql db.
A column 'TSP' [eg value =2022-12-19T22:06:01.950994] is present in both tables. TSP for all rows inserted in a day is same.
Later in the day, I'm supposed to delete older data.
Currently using 'delete from 'B' where TSP<'today-1day' logic
Is there a way to optimize this delete using index or something?

SSMS suggested to create non clustered index on the table.TSP column.
I tested it but seems there isn't much difference.
If this was the data:
50mil TSP1
50mil TSP2
50mil TSP3
My expectation was it would skip scanning TSP2,TSP3 rows and delete TSP1.
Whereas if table doesn't have index it would need to scan all 150mil rows.

Answer (score 0):

The batched delete operation utilizes a view to simplify the execution plan, and that can be achieved using Fast Ordered Delete Operation. This is achieved by refreshing the table once which in turn reduces the amount of I/O required.

**Below are the sample queries: -**

```
CREATE  TABLE tableA
(
id int,
TSP Datetime  DEFAULT  GETDATE(),
[Log] NVARCHAR(250)
)

WHILE @I <=1000 BEGIN  INSERT  INTO tableA VALUES(@I,  GETDATE()-1,  concat('Log message ', @I)  )  SET @I=@I+1 END
```

**Option 1:-  using CTE**

```
;WITH DeleteData 
AS
(SELECT id, TSP,  Log FROM tableA 
WHERE  CAST(tsp AS  DATE)  =  CAST(GETDATE()  AS  DATE))
 
DELETE  FROM DeleteData
```

**Option 2:-  using SQL views**

```
CREATE  VIEW VW_tableA AS (SELECT  *  FROM tableA WHERE  CAST(tsp AS  DATE)  =  CAST(GETDATE()-1  AS  DATE))

delete  from VW_tableA
```

**Reference 1:** An [article](https://www.johnsansom.com/fast-sql-server-delete/) by John Sansom on fast-sql-server-delete.

**Reference 2:** Similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955435/optimizing-delete-on-sql-server).